# Problem with element positioning in JS / HTML

Tags: javascript, css

I need help to make a ray directed from the center of the game to the mouse cursor, but there were problems with the offset of top and left. The line is somewhere near the mouse and I don't understand what it is connected with. Site: https://moomoo.io.

[Debug video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKxb1.jpg).

Code:

```js
let line = document.createElement('div');
line.id = 'line';
document.body.appendChild(line);
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
document.querySelector('html').onmousemove = function(event) { // I wrote in the html selector so you can run here. There should be a gameCanvas
  event = event || window.event;
  console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
  x = event.offsetX;
  y = event.offsetY;
}
let canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas')
setInterval(function draw_line() {
  delta_x = x - (document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2);
  delta_y = y - (document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2);
  theta_radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
  console.log(theta_radians);
  line.setAttribute('style', `border: 2px solid lime; width: 200px; -webkit-transform: rotate(${theta_radians}rad); position: absolute; top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px; height: 0`);
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding a new canvas ontop of the screen and drawing it like that?

It is way easier to control a canvas that hasn't been transformed / translated yet.

I wrote a sample script that I believe should work fine.

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

let styles = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 9999,
    pointerEvents: 'none'
}

Object.assign(canvas.style, styles);

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

let centerX = width / 2;
let centerY = height / 2;
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```